# Comment not displayed php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form which send data to my database, and with this form i can put a comment under my post, but the problem is that : when i goes to one posts for comment it i have (first) to insert a comment and after inserted a comment i can see the other comments, i'm not sure where is the problem

Form php

```
<?php 

    echo "<form class='form-horizontal well' method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
    <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='message' class='col-lg-2 control-label'>Comment:</label>
    <div class='col-lg-10'>
    <textarea name='message' placeholder='Write your comment...' class='form-control' rows='4'></textarea>
    </div></div><br>
    <div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2'>
    <button name='commentSubmit' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Comment</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>";

    getComments($conn);

?>
```

Comments function php

```
function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $users = $_POST['users'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (users, date, message, id) VALUES  ('$users', '$date', '$message', '$id')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn) {
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = $id ORDER BY cid DESC");
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
            echo $row['users']."<br>";
            echo $row['date']."<br>";
            echo nl2br($row['message']);
        echo "</p>
        </div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're hard-inserting `id` in the table. Normally those values are auto-generated. Is that a reference to some other table's ID?

Comment: the id call the id of the post in the page so i can display the relative comment of the post

Comment: This is wrong I am pretty sure `action='".setComments($conn)."'` For a start `setComments()` does not return anything

Comment: The action attribute should be the name of a PHP script like `somescript.php`

Comment: oh yes sure,ok  i change it

Comment: Normally you have something like a `posts` table with an `id` column that's `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then to make comments you insert with `post_id` referencing that post. The comments table has its own `id` column that identifies the unique comment.